# using ifnull with index creation in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing, ifnull

I am trying to create an index in MySQL whereas the query will first check what column is not null. After checking, it will create the index on the column that is not null. However, I am not successful in creating this and it says I have an error, can someone help me? please see my code below

```
create index IDX_KSE_NO_01 on tb_kse(ifnull(ss_no, id_no);
```

Comment: What is the goal?  `ORDER BY ISNULL(...)`?  Or `SELECT ISNULL...`?  Or shrinking the index?  Or not displaying those with `NULL`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL does not support function-based index. You should create normal index:

```
create index IDX_KSE_NO_01 on tb_kse(ss_no);
create index IDX_KSE_NO_02 on tb_kse(id_no);
```

And rewrite your query (OR-Expansion):

```
SELECT *
FROM tb_kse WHERE ss_no = ?
UNION 
SELECT *
FROM tb_kse
WHERE ss_no IS NULL AND id_no = ?;
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=7b7c3d76c7fdd87cee894d7a298bcfe2)**

---

Another way is to create generated column and create index on top of it:

```
CREATE TABLE tb_kse(id_no INT, ss_no INT,
       gen_col INT GENERATED ALWAYS AS (ifnull(ss_no, id_no)) STORED);

create index IDX_KSE_NO_01 on tb_kse(gen_col);

SELECT *
FROM tb_kse
WHERE gen_col = ?;
```

**[DBFiddle Demo 2](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=3592f1ef9edf1bc14405a4be5dd51e45)**

Comment: The two indexes should be replaced by one composite index: `(ss_no, id_no)` -- such will work for the first `SELECT` and work much more efficiently for the second.

Answer (score 3):

@lad2025 is correct that MySQL does not support function-based indexes ([like PostgreSQL does](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/indexes-expressional.html)), but MySQL 5.7 introduced a feature for [virtual generated columns](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-generated-columns.html) based on expressions, and then you can create an index on a virtual column.

```
ALTER TABLE tb_kse ADD COLUMN either_no VARCHAR(10) AS (IFNULL(ss_no, id_no));
CREATE INDEX IDX_KSE_NO_01 ON tb_kse(either_no);
```